# JSF: Embed PrimeFaces enabled Composite Component by URL

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'd like to embed my JSF 2.2 composite components in the iFrames of another application, and need a way to reference them by URL directly.

For example, I create a composite tag in: src/main/webapp/resources/petstore/PetList.xhtml

If I embed it in my home page using the tag  it renders fine.

If I try to access it by URL directly...
http://localhost:8080/PetStoreApp/resources/petstore/PetList.xhtml
...The page is rendered without any styling, JavaScript, etc... which are resource bundles mostly bundled with PrimeFaces (v5.0.18)

If anyone knows a strategy to do this 'the right way' in a PrimeFaces/JSF application, that would be much appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thank you for your continued contribution to the JSF ecosystem.

Respectfully, I don't feel that the link you've provided answers my question.

Instead of restrict access to components in the /resources folder, I am trying to facilitate access.

As for security, I will be passing user credentials on the URL, embedding components in a frame, and my AuthFilter checks for the credentials and validates them against a 3rd party security framework.

Comment: The problem is that when I access composites in the resources folder directly, resources hosted by the PrimeFaces framework aren't resolving in the browser.

Comment: This could very well be a PrimeFaces issue, now that I think about it out loud.  Maybe composites only inherit the PrimeFaces javascript, css, and image assets when they are embedded in pages at the root level of the FacesServlet?